# Angular 6/PHP Http failure during parsing for

Tags: php, mysql, angular6

I am currently learning angular 6 and have problems with my connection to the database.

```
addData(nachname: any, vorname: any, telefon: any) {

return this.client.post('http://localhost/api/add.php', {
  nachname,
  vorname,
  telefon
}).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

}

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ".((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) ?                
 $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : "*"));
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type,           
 access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control- 
 allow-headers');

 $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "telefonauskunft");

 if(!$db){
     exit("Verbindungsfehler: ".mysqli_connect_error());
 }

 $db -> set_charset('utf8');

 $model = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $sql = "Insert Into telefonauskunft ('Nachname', 'Vorname', 'Telefon')
        Values ('$model -> Nachname', '$model -> Vorname', '$model ->           
 Telefon');";
 if($model->Nachname){
     $qry = $db->query($sql);
 }
 $db->close();
 ?>
```

These are my codes. I got a normal select query with this.client.get (...).

Unfortunately I get with this code

> error
>   :
>   {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp…,
>
> Http failure during parsing for

Where is my problem? I thank you in advance for answers and help

Comment: JSON cannot start with `<`. It's most likely an HTML error page or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should print something out in your PHP file, for instance a boolean value stating that the database query was successful. Ideally, you should follow common JSON API guidelines, cf. http://jsonapi.org/format/upcoming/

```
print json_encode($db->query($sql));
```

Comment: the print does not really help for my problem.
I think so I follow the common api. Thank you for your answer